# How to calculate intrinsic curvature of metric perturbation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmological-inflation

I'm reading a paper on cosmological perturbations.(https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4944.pdf) When FRW metric is perturbed to 2nd order, we have (see Eqs.(2.15) in that paper)
$$
g_{00}=-a^2(1+2\phi_1+\phi_2)\\
g_{0i}=a^2\left(B_{1i}+\frac12B_{2i}\right)\\
g_{ij}=a^2[\delta_{ij}+2C_{1ij}+C_{2ij}]
$$
while $g^{00},g^{0i}$ and $g^{ij}$ has even more terms added. Then in Eq.(3.13) of that paper, an intrinsic curvature is given to be ${}^{(3)}R_1=\dfrac{4}{a^2}\nabla^2\psi_1$. I'm not sure if this refers to the Ricci scalar calculated using perturbed metric above, or something else? Besides, if it is the case, do I have to calculate all the Christoffel symbols first, and then Riemann tensor, ..., and finally get the Ricci scalar? Is there any symbolic operation tool that can help me with this work? Or maybe more generally, how can I do calculations in perturbation theory faster, as it really takes me much time to solve a problem like this one.